# Kali linux mirrors displays

Tags: multiple-monitors, kali-linux

I have two monitors hooked up to my custom built PC. I have Ubuntu and Kali Linux installed in a dual boot configuration. On Ubuntu my monitors extend the view. On Kali the monitors mirror each other. When going into the Display settings on Kali Linux it only detects one monitor. Both of my monitors are hooked up to a Radeon R7 260X Graphics Card. I have tried in the past to install graphics drivers but it left Kali Linux unbootable. How can I get Kali Linux to extend the view so I can take advantage of both of my monitors?

Answer (score 0):

Because Kali is based on Debian, this might be worth looking at:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82352/multiple-screens-on-debian

An xrandr how-to is here: https://pkg-xorg.alioth.debian.org/howto/use-xrandr.html

This also may be of help: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=79285

There is an outside chance this may work, too: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-set-up-multiple-monitors-in-linux/step4/set-up-X-for-multiple-screens/